# How to create a registration flask form that affects two tables in order to link the a device to its owner

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-admin, user-registration, flask-security

I’m developing a web application that visualizes sensor data so the users can monitor their devices. The web application uses Flask-Security and Flask-Admin to facilitate the user management and visualization.

The user data is stored in a user table.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
   last_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
   email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
   password = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

The controller table has foreign key pointing to the user id in the user table.

```
class Controller(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   controller_id = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

The register template

```
<form action="{{ url_for_security('register') }}" method="POST" name="register_user_form">
   {{ register_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
   {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.email) }}
   {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.controller_id) }}
   {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.first_name) }}
   {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.last_name) }}
   {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.password) }}
   {% if register_user_form.password_confirm %}
   {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.password_confirm) }}
   {% endif %}
   {{ render_field(register_user_form.submit, class="btn btn-primary") }}
</form>
```

Looks like this on the page
[Register Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFLvK.png)

The problem is that the user registration form doesn’t affect the controller table. I use extended validation form in order to add more fields.

```
class ExtendedRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
   first_name = StringField('First Name')
   last_name = StringField('Last Name')
   controller_id = StringField('Controller ID', [Required()], default="")
```

The new user has to be created first, and then the device can be linked to the user id, but the data is sent using the same form.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic here - you have to provide the data to your forms - Flask-Security doesn't do any magic query generation. In this case - I think you just need to implement the 'register' context processor and grab the controller id.
Read more here: https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customizing.html#views

Comment: Thanks @jwag!
Because Flask-Security provides an abstraction, I don’t know where the data from the form goes and how to process it.

I’ve experience with Flask-Login and Flask-WTF,  so was expecting something like:
form = RegisterForm()
email = form.email.data 

As far as I understood the context processor adds context to the form, so I can add a new variable or method. I tried it and added some extra variables in the register form, but this is not what I’m looking for.

From the form data I want to create a new user and then a new controller related to it.

Comment: I interpreted your question as wanting to add the controller id to the form. In order to add functionality  to register - the easiest thing is to subscribe to the user-registered signal:
https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#signals

Comment: Actually I really wanted to add the controller id to the form, because it came via post request form the device, so your suggestion was very useful. I was going to do that using the render template. I'm posting the solution using  signals.

Answer (score 0):

That solved the problem when using Flask-Security.

```
@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def user_registered_sighandler(app, user, confirm_token):
    default_role = user_datastore.find_role("user")
    user_datastore.add_role_to_user(user, default_role)
    form = ExtendedRegisterForm()
    controller_id = form.controller_id.data
    controller = Controller.query.filter_by(controller_id=controller_id).first()
    controller.user_id = user.id
```

This is the solution when using Flask-Security-Too.

```
@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def user_registered_sighandler(app, user, confirm_token, form_data):
    default_role = user_datastore.find_role("user")
    user_datastore.add_role_to_user(user, default_role)
    controller_id = form_data["controller_id"]
    controller = Controller.query.filter_by(controller_id=controller_id).first()
    controller.user_id = user.id
```